# Browser loads best matching image

Tags: javascript, html, image, loading, filenames

Very simple Problem.

Files in Directory:

- [IMG] tile_3_3.jpg
- [IMG] tile_4_2.jpg
- [IMG] tile_4_3.jpg
- [IMG] tile_4_4.jpg
- [IMG] tile_5_2.jpg
- [IMG] tile_5_3.jpg
- [IMG] tile_5_4.jpg
- [IMG] tile_6_2.jpg
- [IMG] tile_6_3.jpg
- [IMG] tile_6_4.jpg
- [IMG] tile_7_2.jpg
- [IMG] tile_7_3.jpg
- [IMG] tile_7_4.jpg
- [IMG] tile_8_2.jpg
- [IMG] tile_8_3.jpg

I am loading many images by try and error. Means: if the image was not found im searching in a other folder. Ist not the best method but i have to.

The Problem:
If i try to load the image *tile_3_**5**.jpg* i get *tile_3_**3**.jpg*.
http://www.hs-augsburg.de/~keckardt/demonstrator/img/tiles/12_0_r/tile_3_5.jpg

Looks like i get the best matching image.

Comment: Which code? I think there is no code needed. Just use a normal Browser. Could this be a Server Problem?

Comment: interestingly enough, you can try accessing `tile_3_[0-9].jpg` and it will redirect to `tile_3_3.jpg`. However, trying the same with `tile_4_X.jpg` gives [this](http://www.hs-augsburg.de/~keckardt/demonstrator/img/tiles/12_0_r/tile_4_5.jpg). It seems you implemented a piece of code that looks for a picture with a name close to the one put in the url. It seems to be working fine though. Is this behaviour unwanted ? What is the problem ?

Comment: The Problem? This behaviour is unwanted. I just worked on the Client Side but not at the Server. I just uploaded the images and get the wrong image from every browser(Mobile-Dektop Chrome-IE-Firefox).

Comment: How do you load the pictures ? The problem must lie here. Howevever you shouldn't get issues about loading the wrong image. Loading `tile_3_3.jpg` will load the good picture. You shouldn't call `tile_3_5.jpg` if there isn't such a picture on your server anyway

Comment: _How do you load the pictures ?_ I open up a browser. Write the link in the adress bar and press Enter. I have the Problem even if im not using my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Apache webserver redirecting. It might be, that there are some [redirect rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) somewhere in a `.htaccess` file or the global config.

Otherwise, a more esoterical possibility is [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html). Is there any `*.var` file around?

Comment: There is no `*.var` and the `.htaccess` is empty. But the `tile_4_X.jpg` is interesting. Seams like the Server has more than one choice and just returns no image. But how to deactivate/overwrite the auto choice?

Comment: Hm. Have you tried asking over at ServerFault? They may have more experience there...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if your htaccess is empty or you haven't one, try this, which solved this crazy problem for me:

```
    # disables auto-complete and finding of similar named files":
    #  
    CheckSpelling off
```